# Rails retrieving wrong styles?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

After making a relatively basic Rails application, I tried to add some styling. I have two controllers: "welcome" and "content". I wanted to make the links in "welcome" orange and in "content" red.

I started by adding the following (plus some other styling) style to /app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

```
a{
  display:inline-block;
  line-height:20px;
  padding:2px 10px;
  color:white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Subsequently, I added the following to /app/assets/stylesheets/content.scss:

```
a{
  background-color:red;
}
```

And of course the following to /app/assets/stylesheets/welcome.scss:

```
a{
  background-color:orange;
}
```

All the style seem to be displaying correctly, except that the link boxes in "content" are orange instead of red! If I change the color from orange to something else, the "content" link color will change to that as well.

Why is the "content" part of my app not loading the correct style? Is this a specificity issue?

I searched here and I found mostly people having issues with cached styles, but that's not my problem as I can change the "welcome" style and have the other change with it. It's simply loading from the wrong location...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would go into your dev tools and look at your asset sources and make sure that the file is being compiled down into your CSS files.

If it is, then I would go and use your inspection tool in your browser (I use chrome dev tools) to inspect the element you're attempting to target and look. Usually, Chrome shows me what styles are being applied to the target, and which one is actually being computed. Sometimes, you'll have styles that get taken over.

It sounds mostly to me like you're applying both styles to the link boxes. Unless you have more specific classes above your a element that is targeting the different elements on the page, I think the welcome.scss file is getting compiled after your content.scss file, and the way css works is if you have two different styles affecting one element, the one that comes after will actually be the one computed.

It sounds to me you need to be more specific with your selectors. Usually what I do is add a class with the view name right at the top div. So... something like  right at the top of the welcome page. That way you're able to something like this:

```
.content a{ 
  background-color: red;
}
```

And it'll apply only to the  elements in the content section.

With CSS, you really have to be careful to be very specific about what elements on the page you're targeting. Otherwise, you end up getting wonky styles showing up all over the place.

Comment: You are right, the red color is being overridden by the orange. It seems that both the welcome.scss and content.scss try to set the styling for the entire site.

Why does that happen? Why is the welcome.scss applied as well under "content"?

Edit: I could of course solve this by adding containers with .welcome and .content classes, and then adding .class a{background-color:somecolor} but that seems to defeat the purpose of having different stylesheets to begin with...

Comment: Yup! You can't think of CSS files the way you do with controllers. CSS + JS will be compiled and applied to everything across the entire site. So make sure you're very careful about what selectors you're applying things to. Make sure to always tie JS & CSS to specific classes on each page.

Comment: So is there even any point in using the controller-specific stylesheets rails generates? It seems I might as well just put everything (with classes) into application.css

Comment: I think controller-specific assets are a little misleading in terms of name. They're "controller-specific" in the sense that it'll help you organize your CSS and JS to each of your controllers/views. In actuality though, they both get compiled down into one application.js/application.css file.

Comment: Hmm so they're useful for organizing your CSS, but you'll still need to use classes for each controller. Bit misleading indeed but at least I understand it now, thanks!